# How to get nginx to retry a static file if it doesn't exist

Tags: asynchronous, nginx, thumbnails

I have an application server that generates image thumbnails with the URLs handled as static resources by nginx.  Currently this is a synchronous process, so the image is there when the request comes through.

The nginx config for the images is straightforward:

```
location /image/cache/ {
    alias /var/www/image/cache/;
}
```

However, rather than making the application block, I was hoping to generate the URL, but asynchronously generate the corresponding file, freeing up the app server.  The problem then becomes one of dealing with an image request in nginx for which there might not *yet* be a file.

Is there a way to configure nginx to wait and retry on static resources that aren't there yet?

An alternative might be to wire up an application call to ensure that the file is returned when it's available, I'm open to ways of doing that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use error_page @failback to notify you application/browser that thumbnail is not here yet

```
location /image/cache/ {
    alias /var/www/image/cache/;
    error_page         404 @fallback;
}

location @fallback {

    # image is not ready, so handle this situation here

}
```

There is common practice to generate thumbs on demand and cache them as a static files. Is it so expensive in you case ? Could you please explain the reasons behind your decision I mean make thums asynchronously

Comment: Great idea! To explain my thinking, if there are, for example, 3 new (non-cached) images on a page, then generating the thumbnails inline (which includes resizing and optimizing for size) slows performance of that page request. I'm planning to pre-cache various thumbnail sizes on upload instead, but thought I'd seek out other possible approaches.  In terms of my initial question, I believe you've answered it, so thank you! :)

Comment: Keep in mind that nginx has some ability to transform images take a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html